# How can I define custom validation using a custom Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My main goal is to avoid repeating the same set of validation rules for each occurrence of a type of input field, e.g. a phone number, and to define all validation for such a type, in one place only. Right now, I find myself searching for all phone number fields and adding at least two directives to each one, e.g;

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Proposer.ContactDetails.CellPhoneNumber" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" ng-minlength="10" />
```

I'm sure I could even go over-the-top with an `ng-phone-number` (custom) directive, but I'm more looking for something like `ng-validate="phoneNumber"`, where this directive will look for a validation function called `phoneNumber` and apply it to the model. I'm more than happy to write such a directive, but I am wondering if there isn't already something available.

Comment: No, there is no built-in directive like that. You can write custom one, but how would you set regexp for pattern, length for maxlength, etc. I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: write one directive in that verify min length & regx..& then on basis of validation condition set balidate of that input field using `$setValidity`

Comment: @ProfK can't trivialize phone numbers simply because internationally there are a wide variety of patterns as well as whether country code is needed or not

Comment: Really not understanding the question then. Can add the length to pattern if you want to get rid of one attribute or as suggested above create your own phone directive you can use on any project

Comment: @charlietfl Adding length to the pattern is a step in the direction I want, but a further step would be to avoid even repeating the pattern literal on each phone number. If we decided to allow other chars, right now would have to manually update all phone number inputs.

Comment: numerous ways around that...define pattern as constant or use own directive and do updates in one place only etc